# Use jQuery to limit number of <br> characters to 2 and then wrap all text after second <br> character with new div

Tags: jquery, html, regex, replace, word-wrap

I'm dealing with a proprietary content-management system, which spits out data on a page that the client has added, but in order to not break the layout of the page, it needs to be handled in a very specific way.  That content looks something like this:

```
<div class="bio">
    <div class="title">Jane Doe</div>
    <div class="description">
        Founder
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Jane has 12 years' experience running a syndicated talk-show about 
        being an esteemed career-woman.
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that this content is dynamic, but it will always have the same basic format...a name, then a job title, then some number of line breaks, and then a brief statement.  First of all, I need for there to be exactly two line breaks.  So if jQuery sees just **one** line break, it should add another one right behind it.  If it sees **three** line breaks (as in this case), it should remove the third one.  *After jQuery does that*, I'd like it to wrap all of the text after the second line break, but before the end of the div, in a new container with a class of `to-remove`...so that would basically be the description portion.  The reason for that is because at a certain breakpoint, I need the description text to go away.  What I'm hoping to achieve is something like this:

```
<div class="bio">
    <div class="title">Jane Doe</div>
    <div class="description">
        Founder
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="to-cut">
            Jane has 12 years' experience running a syndicated talk-show 
            about being an esteemed career-woman.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that one line break has been removed (so that there are two) and that all of the text after the second line break has been wrapped in a new container.  As I've no idea whatsoever how to achieve this, I don't have any jQuery code to show, but if anyone knows how to do this and can lay it out here, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are looking for a solution to be working or help on a possible algorithm with jquery (that I can provide).

I would do as follow in a most understandable way :

1. loop on all the class description using (".description").each(...)
2. count the number of < br > if not enough add one, too much remove them using the functions:

   (look for the doc) `.find("br") (and .find().length) ? .insertAfter() : .remove`
3. select the remaining text and insert it inside a new div

    `.append('<div class="to-cut"> </div>')`

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I wouldn't respond because you've shown no effort what so ever, just a request to others to give you a solution for free. However I was in a mood to solve this simple problem for practice.

> but it will always have the same basic format

If so, there is no need for regexes or fancy stuff, just DOM manipulation:

```
var description = document.getElementsByClassName('description')[0],
    // if there is only one, you'd need a better selector in your case probably
    children = description.childNodes,
    br = 0, lastBr, div;

for(var i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i++) { // loop over all nodes in description
    if(children[i].nodeType === 1 // if it is an Element
       && children[i].tagName === 'BR') { // if it is <br>
        br++; lastBr = children[i]; // for later use
        if(br > 2) { // remove unwanted
            description.removeChild(children[i]);
            i--; l--; // reset counter
        }
    }
    if(i > 0 && children[i].nodeType === 3 // not the first text node
       && children[i].textContent.trim().length > 0) { // and not empty
        div = document.createElement('div'); // create the div
        div.className = 'to-cut'; // give it a class
        div.appendChild(children[i]); // transfer text content
        description.appendChild(div); // put it in
    }
}

if(br < 2) { // add new <br> when necessary
    description.insertBefore(document.createElement('br'), lastBr); // add it before the one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.description').html($('.description')
        .html()
        .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")
        .replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')
        .split('<br>')
        .filter(function(e) { return e.trim() !== ''; })
        .join('<br><br><div class="to-cut">') + "</div>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7bfqub0w/1/

Comment: You ought to explain this to me if you are gonna use this :)

Answer (score 0):

> Note that this content is dynamic, but it will always have the same
>   basic format

Assuming that statement is true, the following could work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".description").each(function () {
        var title = $(this).html().split('<br>')[0].trim();
        var cleanedEl = $(this).find('br').remove();
        var toCut = $(this).html().replace(title, '');
        $(this).html(title + '<br><br><div class="to-cut">' + toCut + '</div>');
    }); // end description each
});
```

See working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imoshtokill/marz5Lrq/)